# Can't get django-inplaceedit to work

Tags: django, django-templates, edit-in-place, django-inplaceedit

The top of my HTML template contains:

```
{% load inplace_edit %}
```

Header part contains:

```
{% inplace_static %}
```

Then in my body contents I am doing:

```
{% inplace_edit "action.action_state" %}
```

But it's not working. I have installed:

```
'bootstrap3',
'inplaceeditform_bootstrap',   # it is very important that this app is placed before inplaceeditform and inplaceeditform_extra_fields
'inplaceeditform',
'inplaceeditform_extra_fields',
'bootstrap3_datetime',
```

I have tried `'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',` both enabled and disabled.

It shows up as a clickable text, but when I click/double-click nothing happens. How do I get it to work?

Thanks,

Hec

Comment: It's possible that you have some javascript error (unrelated with django-inplaceedit). If you use chrome or firefox see the console. You have a test project here https://github.com/goinnn/django-inplaceedit-bootstrap/tree/master/testing

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Goin. I checked the console on Firefox and it says [10:38:54.354] Empty string passed to getElementById(). @ http://localhost:8000/static/srt/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4 Not entirely sure what's causing that though.

Comment: OK I figured it out. My JQuery was not being imported before being called. Had to Move the JQuery import scripts to the top, inside the head block. Thanks much @Goin!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying @Goin's suggestion I found that my JQuery files were not being correctly imported. had to move:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="{% static 'srt/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="{% static 'srt/js/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
```

to the top of my header block. Anyone working with Bootstrap, please make sure you import JQuery as the first thing in your templates.

Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, if you have another doubt, you could see this template: https://github.com/goinnn/django-inplaceedit-bootstrap/blob/master/testing/testing/app/templates/app/index.html

Comment: I am having the same issue, but moving the jQuery script to the top didn't fix it for me, were you getting a jQuery.deferred exception?

Comment: @Goin could you help me getting my inplace_edit working?  I feel like my problem might be something trivial like I load something in the wrong place or i need another app installed but I cannot figure it out

Comment: @Catherine I'm sorry but I'm very busy... I don't have any free time :-(